# How to do ratio's and greater than and less than in C++

Tags: c++

Im writing this program from "Programming and principles with C++" and i need to write a program that takes too integers and finds the sum, difference, greater and less than value, and ratio.

For some reason i can't get greater than and less than to work. It doesn't actually perform the function. It just simple prints the numbers ie: 4 will be less than 2.

My second problem is how do i write a equation that will do ratios for me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {char ch;cin>>ch;}
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    cout<<"Enter two values.\n";
    cin>>a; cin>>b;
    if (a > b);cout<< a << " Is greater than " << b << "\n";
    if(a < b);cout<< a << " Is less than " << b << "\n";
    cout<<a << " plus " << b << " is " << a+b << "\n"; 
    cout<<a << " minus " << b << " is " << a-b << "\n";
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem doesn't lie with the specific operators, but what context they're contained in.

Comment: Remove semi colons after if condition

Comment: Remove the semicolon after if(a>b); and if(a<b);

Answer (score 2):

First you need to remove the semi colons after if (a>b) and if (a < b).

To do ratios, I suggest finding the greatest common factor between a and b, and then executing the following line:

`cout<<"Ratio of "<<a<<" and "<<b<<" is "<<(a/gcd)<<":"<<(b/gcd);`

Where gcd is the greatest common factor of a and b.

Comment: +1. Figuring out the GCD algorithm and then implementing it is a fun little task for someone who's starting :)

Comment: Why would i use the Euclidean algorithm when i could just use "float" instead of "int" and "cout>>(a/b)"

Comment: If you use float instead of int, then for a case like a=14 and b=4 you'll get your output as 3.5.  I have assumed that you want to print the ratio as 7:2 instead, if so, then using the Euclidean algorithm is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code snippet answers all your questions.

```
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
  {
  float a,b;
  cout<<"Enter 2 numbers";
  cin>>a>>b;

  cout<<"Plus = "<<(a+b)<<"\n";
  cout<<"Minus = "<<(a-b)<<"\n";
  cout<<"Greater = "<<((a>b)?a:b)<<"\n";
  cout<<"Smaller = "<<((a<b)?a:b)<<"\n";
  cout<<"Ratio = 1:"<<(1/(((a<b)?a:b)/((a>b)?a:b)));
  }
```

Comment: This is the logic. If you want to have a non-decimal value for the cases such as when the user inputs a=18 and b=5, modify the source code accordingly. Here it results a ratio of 1:3.6 which itself is correct.